# Is there a way to combine only two padding property directions?

Tags: css

I often encounter situations where I want to change the `padding-left` and `padding-right` (or `border-left` and `border-top`, etc.) of an element, but leave the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` as it otherwise would have been.

2 options:

1. `{padding-left: D; padding-right: C;}`
2. `{padding: A B C D;}`

where in option 2 I have to use Inspect Element to get the present values of `A` and `C`. Option 1 has the disadvantage of being wordy.

So, is there a third option where I can write `{padding: A B C D;}` except use some CSS word that means "what it would have been if I didn't specify it" for `A` and `C`?

Comment: It would be {padding: 0 B 0 D;} if you don't want to specify for A and C.

Comment: @zsherman is correct. if you specify values for padding, margin, etc, it'll overwrite whatever "it otherwise would have been".

Comment: There is nothing like that. Use the wordy approach.

Answer (score 4):

Padding is a special property in CSS, because it has different 'signatures'. As far as I am aware, you **can't do something like** `padding: initial initial 1em 1em`, but you can use these shorthand properties:

From [developer.mozilla.com](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

```
/* Apply to all four sides */
padding: 1em;

/* vertical | horizontal */
padding: 5% 10%;

/* top | horizontal | bottom */
padding: 1em 2em 2em; 

/* top | right | bottom | left */
padding: 2px 1em 0 1em;
```

Unfortunately, it looks like you will have to spell them out individually if you want to only do `padding-bottom` and `padding-left`, or a combination similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to padding you can do something like:

```
.classname {padding: 10px inherit;}
```

That will set 10px for the top and bottom, and it will inherit the padding of its parent element.

Another option is:

```
.classname {padding: 10px initial;}
```

Initial will use the default value which is set for that element.

Depending on the types of elements, sometimes you use `auto` instead of `initial`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. This is a nice syntax to have but for whatever reason, we don't have it. See shermanzach's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all four padding properties are set to 0.

You can set the padding with the shorthand notation, for example:

```
.yourclass{
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

The order of elements in the shorthand version are: top, right, bottom, left.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about already styled properties, such as pre-defined styles for an element(s), and he doesn't want to override certain "sides", but doesn't want to write them out, and would rather use shorthand. BTW, welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use another class to override the first one.

```
.first {
    padding: 5px;
}

.second {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

<div class="first second">no left/right padding</div>
```